# Orleans Error while Initializing Orleans Client

Tags: orleans

I am getting below error when I try to deploy to the azure.  I am doing basic hello world app. Can someone please give some insights.  I have attached the logs below.

I am using :: Version 1.1.0-beta2

The silos start properly as per the log files but it cant initialize the Client in azure. I am using the below config file in the Client.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <!-- 
    This is a sample client configuration file for use by an Azure web role acting as an Orleans client. 
    The comments illustrate common customizations.
    Elements and attributes with no comments should not usually need to be modified.
    For a detailed reference, see "Orleans Configuration Reference.html".
   -->
<ClientConfiguration xmlns="urn:orleans">
  <!-- 
    To turn tracing off, set DefaultTraceLevel="Off" and have no overrides. To see a minimum of messages, set DefaultTraceLevel="Error".
    For the trace log file name, {0} is the silo name and {1} is the current time. 
    Setting WriteTraces to true will cause detailed performance information to be collected and logged about the individual steps in the
    message lifecycle. This may be useful debugging performance issues.
    -->
  <Tracing DefaultTraceLevel="Off" TraceToConsole="false" TraceToFile="{0}-{1}.log" WriteTraces="false">
    <!--
        To get more detailed application logging, you can change the TraceLevel attribute value to "Verbose" or "Verbose2".
        Depending on the log levels you have used in your code, this will cause additional messages to be written to the log.
        -->
    <TraceLevelOverride LogPrefix="Application" TraceLevel="Info" />
  </Tracing>
</ClientConfiguration>
```

PS::
I figured it out after enabling the fusion logs. I could see  1 dll was not loaded properly. The issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using AzureClient. It handles all configuration automatically.

Please refer to https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/tree/master/Samples/AzureWebSample and follow the same setup as there. The best way is to close that AzureWebSample  and add your own grains and logic.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Orleans are you using? If you included http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Orleans.Templates.Interfaces/ in the project, the invoker class should have been generated at compile time. Try cleaning up Properties\orleans.codegen.cs files and rebuilding the project.

Comment: I was able to get the silo running but running into issue -- w3wp.exe Error
w3wp.exe Error: 0 : Client.Initialize failed with exc -- One or more errors occurred.. Will try again.  This happens after I deploy to azure, silo works fine based on the logs.  Is there a way to check how to check the logs on the client side.